# how to refresh UX data on a ViewController when its TabBarItem gets tapped?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

In the view controller that has a UITabBarItem, i realized that viewDidLoad() method only gets called the first time when the tab bar item is clicked. So I dont know how to bring up the dynamic graphics when it's clicked the 2nd time. Can some guru help me on this? thanks in advance.

Should I conform to some kind of delegates or should i do it within didSelectViewController method on the root controller of all the tab bars? If i do the later one, it just seems to be weird since i think the controller that has the corresponding tab bar item should render itself instead of doing the rendering on root controller..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i resolved this by using the parameter passed into the callback didSelectViewController(param).

Answer (score 0):

You want to put any code that should run every time the view controller appears in [`viewWillAppear:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear%3a) instead of `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidLoad` is designed for code that should run when the view backed by your UIViewController is created (and then possibly re-created after being thrown away during low-memory situations).